# How to create windows phone app of my existing responsive website?

Tags: windows-phone

I have responsive website and wanted to create app for windows phone. So is there any way to make the same? online or by using any other technology (like phone gap or something else). It means my website URL load on click of app icon.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do that. Basically you have three ways (but there are more!) to consider:

1. **Native universal HTML5/JS app:** Create a native app using HTML5 and Javascript directly. There is a nice jumpstart available in the Microsoft Virtual Academy (MVA): http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-universal-windows-apps-with-html-and-javascript-jump-start
2. **WebView in a C# app:** You can also add a WebView to a C# app and run your code inside a browser. This is done quite often - especially if developers want to port a web app very quickly to Windows Phone since all you have to do is to adjust your paths and you're good to go. There's a video on Channel9 by Bob Tabor: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-13-Working-with-the-Web-View-App-Template (This video is part of another MVA course: WP 8.1 app development for absolute beginners)
3. **3rd party frameworks:** You can use third party libraries like PhoneGap / Cordova to run your code. This is very much like 2. as your code is also executed in a browser. The advantage is that you can easily deploy your code on other platforms but you might run into performance issues under certain circumstances.

So if you want to load your page if you click on your app icon (2) might be your best shot.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 Universal Apps you can do that very easily using the Microsoft project Westminster:
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/uwp-bridges/web-apps

Step by step guide is here: 
http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm

It takes about five minutes to make the app, and then maybe a few hours to polish it, make the right icons from the Windows store etc.